# Factored out loop control in Python

Tags: python, loops, control-structures

I have a for loop in python like this:

```
for item in items:
    onwards = make_flow_decision(item)
    if onwards == 'break':
        break
    elif onwards == 'continue':
        continue
    elif onwards == 'carry_on':
        process_the_item(item)
```

So idea is that flow control for the loop is factored out because it is really complex.

Is there a better way of doing this than passing strings around and checking for special strings like 'continue', 'break', and 'carry_on'?

Looking for ideas generally that make this a little more elegant.

Comment: Can it be split into should_break() and should_continue() methods? (assuming you don't have any genuinely meaningful names you could use like if unauthenticated() break elif not_eligible_for_coupon() continue)

Comment: Theoretically yes, but that'd push the ugliness to two flow decision methods. Not sure it would help too much, at least with this code.

Comment: I guess it depends on what you consider ugly. My suggestion was meant to remove the need to return those magic strings. I suppose the other easy answer is that the `continue` cases can be `filter()`ed out and the "normal" case can be `map()`ed, but the `break` may be tricky depending on how much you care about leaving some but not all items processed at the end.

Comment: This gives me one idea. I could rewrite it so that the `make_flow_decision()` was cheap to check once a break was needed. Then, instead of actually `break`ing out of the loop, I could just continue through it until it's done. It'd mean needless iteration, but if cheap enough that's not so bad. The resulting code could be simplified to, `if press_on: process_the_item()`. And the check would just emulate a break by continuing until the last item.

Comment: Instead of strings, why not use [enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702834/whats-the-common-practice-for-enums-in-python)?

Answer (score 5):

What you could do, is factor out the filtering and breaking into a generator, which can be really handy if that logic is used multiple times, with different processing in the middle.

```
def relevant_items(items):
    for item in items:
        # logic to continue or break/return goes here
        yield item

def process_many_items(items):
    for item in relevant_items(items):
        process_item(item)
```

This does however add an extra layer of indirection, which is probably only worth it if the relevant_items method would make sense outside process_many_items.

Comment: Indeed, `relevant_items` *does* make more sense outside of the processing loop. I dig this approach. Will give it a go.

Comment: Actually, I take it back! Darn. This won't work because some processing of the item has to happen *before* the continue/break/return decision can be made. So the loop is more like, for item in items, calculate some stuff, using that stuff, make a decision, using that decision, continue/break/carry_on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use enumerated types instead of strings, and keep your implementation.

Or, if you don't mind using exceptions you can write:

```
try:
    for item in items:
        if shall_process(item):
            process_the_item(item)
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Here, `shall_process` returns a boolean and can throw an exception to exit the iteration.

Comment: Not a bad approach. The logic feels a little oblique though. Like, it's much easier to understand the flow control of my first example than it is to figure out that `shall_process` is emulating a `break` by throwing an exception. The one thing that might help here though is the `StopIteration` exception. The enums approach seems a little less confusing though, I'll say that.